# Science fiction book cover with man looking up at floating black rectangular "ships" in sky?

Tags: story-identification, cover-art

I remember a SF book cover with a man looking up at a sky full of floating black rectangular box-like (otherwise featureless) ships.  For the life of me, I can't recall what the book was.  Anyone recall it?

Comment: When did you see the book? Was it in English? Did it look old / new? *Any* more details?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1WomfhjyVM

Comment: Did you actually read the book? Can you remember anything about the plot, the characters, the setting? YOu might like to check out [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on asking story-ID questions here - so far you've given us very little to go on, so some more details would be great :-)

Comment: What was the ratio of their sides?

Comment: I thought I remembered a cover of HGTTG showing the Vogon ships that "hung in the air in much the same way that bricks don't", but they were yellow, though that is not my memory of the image I recall (which probably means I'm remembering the movie, where they were grey).

Answer (score 37):

**Possibly *[The Visitors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0283987189)*, by Clifford Simak?**

[image: enter image]]

Comment: Could you put the image in the post? Link-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: I suspect that link won't be right, searching for "The Visitors simak" in google yielded me the cover I was thinking of.

Comment: someone beat me to it... :)

Comment: Seeds - I helped.

Comment: So, someone who's read it, was it *really* the *strangest* novel of alien invasion ever?? I must know!

Comment: Everything I've read by Simak is strange. :)

Comment: I have this exact edition. It was strange, but I agree with @Seeds re Simak.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe ["The Beast" by A.E. Van Vogt or "Farnham's Freehold" by Heinlein.](http://www.icshi.net/sevagram/biblio/beast.php)

There were editions of both with the same cover art:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Possibly also "2001: Space Odyssey" by Arthur C Clark, or the "2010/2061/3001" sequels.  Although in each case I can find, there is only one featureless black monolith on the cover ([link to Google image search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=2001%202010%202061%203001%20space%20odyssey%20novel%20cover&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHzam-y4vNAhUFtBoKHcDkCbsQ_AUIBygB&biw=1223&bih=811)).